# SAPUI5 Table incorrect data after row deletion

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm implementing SAPUI5 app with XML views and SAP backend. I have simple sap.m.Table with delete button on row level. In press handler I'm using `oDataModel.remove(...)` function, which triggers _DELETE_ENTITY method in ABAP.

This works fine, data is deleted in back-end, but after UI is refreshed table displays incorrect data.

When I click delete on second row, last row in table disappear (OK), but only some fields are refreshed - see green box.

[image]

I've tried to add `Model.refresh(true)` in callback function, but it triggers only next back-end call, but changes nothing in UI.

PS.
The two correct values are assigned to formatter function in view definition.

Comment: oModel.remove() should refresh the model after successfully deleting the record. Image link is broken.

Comment: Yes, it should. This command deletes data in backend (OK) and fetch entityset again automatically (SAP returns correct dataset, without deleted row) (OK).
What is more UI is also refreshing automatically (remove last row), but content of lines, that should be moved is not good.

There is a workaround to add dummy formatter function for all columns, but I would like to find cause of the problem.